# WPF TabControl - Templating and create tabs programatically

Tags: .net, wpf, tabcontrol

I am creating one tab control in WPF using ContentTemplate.

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabOrders">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="TabItemTemplate">
                <ScrollViewer Height="550" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0, 10, 0, 100">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10, 20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Button Width="100" Margin="0, 0, 20, 0" x:Name="btnUpload" Click="btnUpload_Click">Upload</Button>
                            <ComboBox Width="250" Margin="0, 0, 20, 0" x:Name="ddlPaperType" DataContext="{Binding paper_id }"></ComboBox>
                            <Button Width="100" Margin="0, 0, 20, 0" x:Name="btnApplyAll" Click="btnApplyAll_Click">Apply All</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ListView x:Name="lvImages" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <UniformGrid Columns="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding FileName}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                                        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPaperType" ItemsSource="{Binding paper_id}"  Margin="5" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValuePath="_id" ></ComboBox>
                                        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />-->
                                    </StackPanel>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

    </TabControl>
```

Creating tab items using the below code:

```
tabOrders.DataContext = DataContext;

        List<TabContext> context = (List<TabContext>)DataContext;
        foreach (TabContext tabContext in context)
        {
            TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
            tabItem.DataContext = tabContext;
            tabItem.Header = tabContext.item.order_number + " - " + tabContext.item.ProductArr.product_name ;
            tabOrders.Items.Add(tabItem);
        }
```

Here issue is that both tabs are showing same content. I am new to WPF and don't know what I am missing. Please advise.

Update : 28-Dec

On Button click I run the below code that binds the data to listview:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (Button)sender;
        var parentPanel = (StackPanel)btn.Parent;
        var cmb = parentPanel.FindChild<ComboBox>("ddlPaperType");

        TabItem currentTab = (TabItem)tabOrders.Items[tabOrders.SelectedIndex];
        var context = (TabContext)currentTab.DataContext;
        cmb.ItemsSource = context.paper_id;
        cmb.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
        cmb.SelectedValuePath = "_id";

        var order_number = context.item.order_number;
        var brand_id = context.item.brand_id._id;

        var parent = btn.Parent;
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        List<UploadFile> images = new List<UploadFile>();
        ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.tif, *.tiff)|*.bmp; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.tif; *.tiff|Photoshp Files (*.psd)|*.psd|Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            foreach (var item in ofd.FileNames)
            {
                images.Add(new UploadFile
                {
                    FileName = item,
                    order_number = order_number,
                    brand_id = brand_id,
                    paper_id = context.paper_id
                });
            }
        }
        var lv = parent.GetParentObject().FindChild<ListView>("lvImages");
        lv.ItemsSource = images;
    }
```

Comment: Please share the ViewModel associated to this View, or how you provide ListView with ItemsSource.

Comment: Updated question to accommodate the code requested.

Comment: You also want to show the class you use to provide DataContext. Why not following MVVM? separating View and ViewModel, and injecting your model in the View (in the codebehind, in .xaml.cs) and testing your ViewModels. What you're doing is highly unreadable, unmaintainable. If you allow me this image, it's a bit like writing in assembly from python. For MVVM, this means using ICommand for your buttons, and `{Binding DatacontextProperty}` for anything data related. You want to use the code-behind only when there is no interaction with the ViewModel (and I see a god function in `btnUpload_Click`)

Comment: Try a static analyser such as Ndepend to see what you're doing wrong in your project, you'll improve radically your engineering.

Comment: In the end, the huge benefit of WPF is this ability to decouple View and ViewModel, and you're not "enjoying" it so far.

Comment: I agree MVVM is a better option, but will that really solve the issue? I think there's something wrong in the way I have used template in tab control.

Comment: It will prevent you from messing up your project, you'll see most of what is wrong as you type, and you'll need less time to update your project. You should use`ControlTemplate` instead of `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Yes, I had to use MVVM and do binding for all controls. It worked as you suggested. Thanks a lot.